# How to wrapping member function to global function in SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I wonder how to wrapping member function to global function in SWIG.

Example,

**test.cpp**

```
class test
{
public:
    void foo1();
    void foo2();
}
```

After Wrapping,

**test.py**

```
class test:
    def foo1():
       ...

def foo2():
    ...
```

how to write *.i file?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a working set of files.  A class definition with no implementation won't work:

test.hpp

```cpp
class test {
public:
    int foo1();
    int foo2();
};
```

test.cpp

```cpp
#include "test.hpp"
int test::foo1() { return 1; }
int test::foo2() { return 2; }
```

Then for the .i file:

```cpp
// Name of the module.  For Python this must be the name of the final
// _test.pyd and test.py files after swig processing and compilation.
%module test

%{
// Code to be inserted in the generated wrapper code.
// The wrapper must be able to call the wrapped code so include the header.
#include "test.hpp"
%}

// This tells swig to wrap everything found in "test.cpp".
// Note it *does not* process #include in this file by default, just
// declaration found directly in the file.
%include "test.hpp"
```

Run SWIG to generate (in this case) `test.py` and `test_wrap.cxx`:

```
swig -python -c++ test.i
```

Compile the wrapper.  I'm doing this directly with MSVC.  The Python include and libs directory must be provided to build the Python extension, and the name of the final Python extension should be _.pyd.

```
cl /EHsc /LD /W3 /Ic:\python310\include /Fe_test.pyd test_wrap.cxx test.cpp /link /libpath:c:\python310\libs
```

Demo:

```py
C:\>swig -python -c++ test.i

C:\>cl /nologo /EHsc /LD /W3 /Id:\dev\python310\include /Fe_test.pyd test_wrap.cxx test.cpp /link /libpath:d:\dev\python310\libs
test_wrap.cxx
test.cpp
Generating Code...
   Creating library _test.lib and object _test.exp

C:\>py
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> t = test.test()
>>> t.foo1()
1
>>> t.foo2()
2
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! 

I have one more question. If i want test class member function use like python global function, how can i do?

For script example,

`import test
test.foo1()  # not test.test().foo1()`

Comment: @happy_S don’t put the function in a class. `test` is a module in this case, so `test.foo1()` would refer to a top level function.

Comment: if foo1 function must be in class how can i do? 